# Liferay and its database model

Tags: java, sql, liferay, database-design

We want to use Liferay but is it possible to create our own database tables with foreign keys and integrity?

Liferay seems to create a lot of stuff and has control over the DB, so I want to know if we'll get into problems trying to do this.

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. You will spend most of the time developing portlets and plugins, that have their own database model (in the same database) that is independent of the portal database model.

You have a choice to use so called Service Builder, which is a source code generator that among other things creates DDL scripts of your data model based on metadata definition. Again, even this data model doesn't depend on Portal database and is based on Hibernate/JPA.

Another choice is to not use Service Builder at all and utilize some JPA implementation or Hibernate directly.

Sometimes one just needs to use portal tables (User, Resources, etc.) and persist data into them but for that you have a service layer already available for you.

Comment: We are always using a different database/schema than the one that Liferay is using. Makes life a lot easier.

Comment: What are the advantages ? If you don't use ServiceBuilder, then apart from database upgrade it shouldn't matter, right ?

Answer (score 2):

There are no foreign keys in the liferay schema and you can't create foreign key relationships with the Liferay service builder.

See [Where are the foreign keys?](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2013318)

Comment: foreign keys are indeed created for the core tables, so you are incorrect in that respect. Liferay does not map an object model to the database and therefore does not know that userId refers to the User_ table so FK constraints are not automatically added from the Service Builder, but can be added manually (verified on 6EE and 6EE SP1)

Comment: 'foreign keys are indeed created for the core tables' Can you name one? I can't see any in my schema.

Comment: ha! time to eat my words. Search terms (ie what should be a FK) are indexed but the actual FK reference is not created. My apologies I clicked the 'index' tab rather than FKs and interpreted it incorrectly.

Comment: Like I said, there are no foreign keys and you can't create them with ServiceBuilder.

Comment: Can you please also refer a good material on why this approach ? The link you suggested lacks details on this.